# Proving that $f(x)=\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan x}$ is not uniformly continuous in $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus

I have the following function: $f(x)=\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan x}$. I'm trying to prove that it's not uniformly continuous in $(0,1)$. As I understand, I need to show that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ does not exist. But I'm struggling to show it. I tried to use some sequences in order to get to some different answers but it looks to difficult to find the limit. How can I do it?

Comment: I do not know if it helps, but a function is uniformly continuous iff it maps equivalent sequences onto equivalent sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Take two sequences
$$a_n=\frac{1}{n\pi}$$
and
$$b_n=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi}$$

then

$$\lim a_n=\lim b_n=0$$
but
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(a_n)=0\ne$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(b_n)=\frac{2}{\pi}$$

So, by sequential caracterisation of the limit,
$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) $ cannot exist.

You can also say
$$\Bigl(\lim_{n\to+\infty}(a_n-b_n)=0\text{ and } \lim_{n\to+\infty} (f(a_n)-f(b_n))\ne 0\Bigr)$$
$$\implies f \text{ is not U continuous at } (0,1)$$

Comment: Why did you show that  for $\lim_{n\to\infty}$. Should not it be  $\lim_{n\to 0}$?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to 0} $ has no sense.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint}$: No matter what you do the denominator will always approach $\frac{\pi}{2}$ so choose subsequences so that

$$\frac{1}{x} = \pm\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n$$

then conclude the limit cannot exist.